# Albus Dumbledore and teachers of the Defense Against the Dark Arts

Tags: harry-potter, defence-against-the-dark-arts

Reading the Harry Potter series, I have this feeling that Dumbledore always got the Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher wrong. Was this on purpose or was it his incompetence?

Comment: _I have this feeling that_... What gives you this feeling?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10563/did-voldemort-actually-curse-the-job-of-defense-against-dark-arts-professor-afte

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40776/how-did-the-curse-on-the-dada-job-work

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91305/did-dumbledore-know-lockhart-was-a-fraud

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73858/why-was-umbridge-hired

Comment: there ya go buddy. ^

Comment: If it was cursed why didn't Dumbledore take away the curse?

Comment: It was cursed in the sense that we think things are cursed, not in the actual magic curse sense. Although, if it was a Magic Curse, and they couldn't deal with it, they'd make a poor Defense v Dark Arts teacher...

Comment: @Nachmen If you have read the entire series, you should know there are certain curses which can't be 'taken away', even by Dumbledore. Some forms of magic are unbeatable (at least they were unbeatable while Harry still went to Hogwarts).

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what you mean by "wrong".

1. Quirrell was *already* a Hogwarts instructor, the Professor of
   Muggle Studies, and was known to be brilliant in Theoretical Dark
   Arts Defense (After all, Voldemort is dead, it's all theory anyhow).
2. Lockhart was the [Brian Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Williams) of the wizarding world... no
   one had any idea that he actually hadn't done any of the things he
   said he did.
3. There was nothing wrong with Lupin - He controlled his Lycanthropy
   with a Wolfsbane potion, and only forgot due to the Scabbers
   incident. While being known and respected, and wasn't a danger to himself, or others, but the wizarding world as a whole dislikes werewolves, and so the prejudice kicked him out.
4. Alastar Moody is a famous Auror, known far and wide for dedication
   against the dark arts. Think of him like a Pre-politics [John
   McCain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_McCain). The fact he was a Death Eater in a war hero suit was unknown until the very last minute.
5. Umbridge was not a decision by Dumbledore, but rather the corrupted
   Ministry of Magic.
6. There's nothing wrong with Snape as a DaDA teacher... He actually
   wanted the position, and since Slughorn took over potions, it was a
   natural fit. He even taught Harry Occlumency, over and above his
   normal teaching.
7. The Carrows were put in place by Voldy himself, as the former headmaster was Dumble-dead.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Excellent answer! You make valid points. However, I would like to point out that Dumbledore (as a wise and knowledgeable wizard) likely suspected that Lockhart was not everything he appeared to be, he also probably figured out that Moody was an impostor much sooner than the end of the year, he just didn't act on it because he didn't know what the plan was and played the long game with Voldemort. As for Lupin - there was no excuse for him forgetting to drink the Potion on a full moon night - he could've killed Harry, Ron and Hermione. He deserved the sack

Comment: @YuriyS And then again if he had taken the time to do that he might have missed the fact Scabbers was actually there; or he might have missed the opportunity to prevent catastrophe. That's just it: it was essentially an emergency and in emergencies anything can happen. And who knows? Maybe it was because of the jinx? Maybe it wasn't 'his doing'? If you want to look at it as the job is jinxed then you could interpret it that it wasn't completely his doing - something had to happen and that's what it was for Lupin.

Answer (score 2):

As seen in this [question and answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10563/did-voldemort-actually-curse-the-job-of-defense-against-dark-arts-professor-afte) the position was cursed by Voldemort. Dumbledore was not incompetent... he would have to search very hard and long just to find a teacher willing to accept the position.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it was out of his control, in other times it was depending on circumstance.

For example, in book 1, Quirrell was the teacher. He was a teacher in the past but because Voldemort (who cursed the DADA post so no one would last more than 3 terms) was possessing Quirrell, he was able to stay longer than others.

In book 2, Lockhart is the teacher. This is because no one else wants the post, not because Dumbledore wanted him in particular. We also learn that the job is essentially cursed.

> "He was the on' man for the job," said Hagrid, offering them a Y
>   plate of treacle fudge, while Ron coughed squelchily into his basin.
>   "An' I mean the on' one. Gettin' very difficult ter find anyone fer Y
>   the Dark Arts job. People aren't too keen ter take it on, see. They're
>   startin' ter think it's jinxed. No one's lasted long fer a while now.
>   -*Chamber of Secrets*

In book 3, chances are looking slim for a teacher, but Lupin (a werewolf who people are reluctant to employ) gets a chance by Dumbledore to teach. He was by peer judgement a very good teacher (approved by Madam Pomfrey, students, and teachers).

In book 4, the Triwizard Tournament takes place, and as Sirius points out that Dumbledore is reading the signs, gets Mad eye Moody to take the post, just for 1 year (pointed out to be an teacher experienced in his field even though he turned out to be Barty Crouch Junior and placed illegal curses on his students)

> If it hurts again, go straight to Dumbledore ­ they're saying he's got Mad­Eye out of retirement, which means he's reading the signs, even if no one else is.
>   *Goblet of Fire*

In book 5, it is in the same position as Book 2. No one wants the job, with the public considering it cursed, however, this time the ministry intervenes and force Dumbledore to employ a ministry witch (Umbridge) in essence to spy and cause trouble at Hogwarts.

In book 6, Dumbledore needed Slughorn in order to obtain a memory, and as Slughorn taught potions, Snape had to move to the vacant role he so longed for (DADA). Dumbledore also knew he was going to die, so he gave Snape his wish at teaching DADA knowing that he would play a larger role when Dumbledore goes in the school anyway (technically Snape didn't last longer than 3 months either, he left before the end of the last term, and came back as a headteacher).

In book 7, Dumbledore was inactive due to being in the afterlife. Not his fault!

Comment: Are there actually three terms to a year at Hogwarts? Isn't it just the autumn and spring terms?

Comment: Although Quirrell was a Hogwarts teacher in the past, he had taught Muggle Studies, not DADA. Also, Voldemort didn't start possessing him until after the failed Gringotts break in.

Comment: Does it say in the books that Voldemort cursed the DADA?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sept to Dec, Jan to Easter, Easter to End of Year.